# Variable unexpectedly being changed in PHPUnit test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have written a simple unit test which is testing that a method on the class under test returns an instance of itself, with the parameters it is passed being untouched.

I.e. `$this->theClass->theMethod($param1, $param2);` should not modify `$param1`, or `$param2` as the method returns `$this`. However, I'm seeing that when I `var_dump($param1)` immediately after running the method, $param1 has been modified.

To give more context:

**Given there is a `User` named *Bob Jones*.**

```
$user = factory(App\User::class, 'withCompany')
        ->make([
            'name' => 'Bob',
            'surname' => 'Jones',
            'member_id' => 1
        ]);
```

**And *Bob* has some meta `UserData` which also has attributes `name` and `surname` (of equal values).**

```
$userData = factory(App\UserData::class)
        ->make($this->mapUserToUserData($user) + ['member_id' => 1]);
```

**When I change the `name` attribute within the `UserData` meta data object to '*Fred*',**

```
$userData->m_field_id_4 = 'Fred';
```

**And I synchronise the data between objects (i.e. I call the method under test)**

```
$this->syncUserData->sync($user, $userData);
```

### Note: At this point - if I ```var_dump($user->name);```, '*Fred*' is output, instead of '*Bob*', as I would expect.

**Then the `User` object should still have the name '*Bob*'.**

```
$originalUser = $this->syncUserData->getOriginalUser();
$syncedUser = $this->syncUserData->getSyncedUser();

$this->assertEquals('Bob', $originalUser->name);
$this->assertEquals('Fred', $syncedUser->name);
```

As the note above states, the `$user` object has been changed, without any direct modification.

For completeness, the full code is below:

**SyncUserDataTest.php**

```
class SyncUserDataTest extends TestCase
{
use UserDataMapper;

protected $syncUserData;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->syncUserData = new App\Helpers\SyncUserData();
}
public function test_it_returns_the_unmodified_user()
{
    $user = factory(App\User::class, 'withCompany')
        ->make([
            'name' => 'Bob',
            'member_id' => 1
        ]);
    $userData = factory(App\UserData::class)
        // And the data is the same
        ->make($this->mapUserToUserData($user) + ['member_id' => 1]);

    $userData->m_field_id_4 = 'Fred';

    $this->syncUserData->sync($user, $userData);

    $originalUser = $this->syncUserData->getOriginalUser();
    $syncedUser = $this->syncUserData->getSyncedUser();

    $this->assertEquals('Bob', $originalUser->name);
    $this->assertEquals('Fred', $syncedUser->name);
}

}
```

**SyncUserData.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class SyncUserData
{
/**
 * Has any data changed.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
private $hasChanged = false;

/**
 * The original User object without modifications.
 *
 * @var \App\User
 */
private $originalUser;

/**
 * The updated User object that has had data synced from the UserData object.
 *
 * @var \App\User
 */
private $syncedUser;

/**
 * Sync data from UserData with a User object.
 *
 * @param   \App\User $user
 * @param   \App\UserData $against
 * @return  $this
 */
public function sync($user, $against)
{
    $this->setOriginalUser($user);

    $updatedUser = $this->applyChangesToUser($user, $against);

    $this->setSyncedUser($updatedUser);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Check if two values are the same.
 *
 * @param string $check
 * @param string $against
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasChanged($check, $against)
{
    if ($check != $against) {
        $this->hasChanged = true;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * @param \App\User $user
 * @return $this
 */
public function setSyncedUser($user)
{
    $this->syncedUser = $user;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param \App\User $user
 * @return $this
 */
public function setOriginalUser($user)
{
    $this->originalUser = $user;
    return $this;
}


/**
 * Get the updated User object with data synced from the UserData object.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getSyncedUser()
{
    return $this->syncedUser;
}

/**
 * Get the original User object.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getOriginalUser()
{
    return $this->originalUser;
}

/**
 * Was any data different between the User and UserData objects.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return bool
 */
public function wasDataChanged()
{
    return $this->hasChanged;
}

/**
 * @param $user
 * @param $against
 */
private function applyChangesToUser($user, $against)
{
    if ($this->hasChanged($user->name, $against->m_field_id_4)) {
        $user->name = $against->m_field_id_4;
    }

    if ($this->hasChanged($user->surname, $against->m_field_id_5)) {
        $user->surname = $against->m_field_id_5;
    }

    return $user;
}

}
```

Quite simply, my question is - how is the `$user` object's `name` attribute being changed?

Comment: Without looking through too much of the code (tl;dr), my inkling is that you're getting confused by objects being passed by reference. If you change the value of variable that shares the same reference, they will all appear updated (though in reality, they're all the same thing).

Comment: Nothing is being passed by reference, and even if it were, the ```sync``` method I pass the object to never directly modifies the ```$user``` object.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference _by default_.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It's not often that you *really* need a clone of an object so in this instance as that *is* the intended functionality it must be explicitly defined. Please feel free to write your last comment as an answer so I can mark it to give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you appear to be having is that objects are passed by reference by default, so when you update one, you update all of them.

Ways around this include (but may not be limited to):

- Using clone (though this only does a shallow copy, so watch for that)
- Serialising then deserialising the object into a new variable